# POSTing Form Fields with Same Name in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am looking to emulate a POST request using Powershell (v4). Fiddler has enabled me to replicate the original in all relevant aspects other than the following:

[image: example of multiple form fields with same name]

I have tried a number of approaches, the easiest to explain / demonstate is probably:

```
invoke-webrequest -Uri "$uri"  `
  -body @{
    _program='/Web/storm'
    SASControlTable='[{"Name":"COL1","Type":"str"},{"Name":"COL2","Type":"str"}]'
    SASControlTable='[{"COL1":"VAL1","COL2","VAL2"}]'
  } -method post  -usedefaultcredentials
```

This gives the error:

> Duplicate keys 'SASControlTable' are not allowed in hash literals.

How do I submit multiple fields with the same name using Powershell?

**Edit:**

My actual http body looks like this:

```
_program=%2FWeb%2Fstorm&_debug=0&_service=default&SASControlTable=%5B%7B%22colName%22%3A%22ACTION%22%2C%22colType%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22colLength%22%3A14%7D%5D&SASControlTable=%5B%7B%22ACTION%22%3A%22INITIALISATION%22%7D%5D
```

Submitting an identical body with Powershell does not give me two parameters for  `SASControlTable` in the WebForms tab of fiddler (and only the second parameter is received by the web server).  This is the issue I am trying to solve..

Comment: As it stands, even if the code ran, you'd get `System.Collections.Hashtable` as the body. How is the actual body text formatted? Fiddler displays an abstraction over the raw body in the tab you show, which doesn't really help you in PowerShell. You can ask Fiddler to create a new request from the given one which would probably be the much easier route.

Comment: Ok, good point - have updated my question with the body details.  How do I ask Fiddler to recreate the request, in such a way that it can be emulated in Powershell?

Comment: did you try $body = '_program=%2FWeb%2Fstorm&_debug=0&_service=default&SASControlTable=%5B%7B%22colName%22%3A%22ACTION%22%2C%22colType%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22colLength%22%3A14%7D%5D&SASControlTable=%5B%7B%22ACTION%22%3A%22INITIALISATION%22%7D%5D'

Comment: @JaquelineVanek - yes, but it does not give me two parameters for `SASControlTable` in the WebForms tab of Fiddler (it's there in the RAW request detail but doesn't get passed to the web server as two parameters)

Comment: idk, i'd try replicating the request exactly as seen in fiddler(raw) -- not just the body but the headers, method etc. btw, since you don't have a method in your example , it defaults to GET, not POST

Comment: I've done exactly that - replicating all relevant aspects (headers, body, method) using Fiddler.  I could add a bunch more code to the question of things I've tried..  But the same named fields do not show through under WebForms, or get received by the web server :-/

Comment: making the same request to https://httpbin.org/post, SASControlTable is actually an array. gonna check Fiddler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about using "here strings"?

```
$body = @"
_program='/Web/storm'
SASControlTable='[{"Name":"COL1","Type":"str"},{"Name":"COL2","Type":"str"}]'
SASControlTable='[{"COL1":"VAL1","COL2","VAL2"}]'
"@

invoke-webrequest -Uri $uri -body $body -method post -usedefaultcredentials
```

PS
you may or may not need double quotes

PPS
most probably the above wont work - have a look at Fiddler's "Raw" tab and replicate the request body in $body

PPPS
or you can make a request, get the forms/fields, populate them and make another request. Have a look at the help

```
Get-Help Invoke-WebRequest -ShowWindow
```

PPPPS

this

```
$body = '_program=%2FWeb%2Fstorm&_debug=0&_service=default&SASControlTable=%5B%7B%22colName%22%3A%22ACTION%22%2C%22colType%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22colLength%22%3A14%7D%5D&SASControlTable=%5B%7B%22ACTION%22%3A%22INITIALISATION%22%7D%5D'

(Invoke-WebRequest https://httpbin.org/post -Method Post -Body $body).content
```

in Posh:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "SASControlTable": [
      "[{\"colName\":\"ACTION\",\"colType\":\"string\",\"colLength\":14}]", 
      "[{\"ACTION\":\"INITIALISATION\"}]"
    ], 
    "_debug": "0", 
    "_program": "/Web/storm", 
    "_service": "default"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "224", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; en-US) WindowsPowerShell/5.1.14393.82"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "94.72.189.16", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

and in Fiddler

[image]

seems just like what you get to me

Comment: The here string didn't work - it just placed all the content in the "_program" variable.  I've tried replicating the body, which submits without error, but the second SASControlTable parameter is not received.   I've also tried the third approach of getting the forms / fields but it wouldn't let me add two values with the same name.

Comment: it seems to be a single field, an array of two, not two fields

Comment: So..  I tried it again using the pre-encoded $body approach (PPPPS), and - it worked!  The httpbin.org/post service was really helpful.  I'm not really sure where things went wrong, I know that our web server has been really intermittent but that doesn't explain the client request.  Thanks for your help.